# abi encoding with selector and additional variable

Tags: solidity, abi, bytes, encoding

I am trying to abi encode a function abc(address, string)

the encoding looks like this

```
Address.delegateCall(abi.encodeWithSignature("abc(address,string)", _address, _string))
```

but I actually want to attach another variable which is not part of the function parameter

```
Address.delegateCall(abi.encodeWithSignature("abc(address,string)", _address, _string, _myaddress))
```

I saw this being possible in Meta transactions trusted forwarder ([here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/a42bf0a79260458b5bb2ea3dcf55947e98383606/contracts/metatx/MinimalForwarderUpgradeable.sol#L61)) contract with abi.encodePacked how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like abi.encode, with signature , with selector all has same underlying encoding same. but packed is compressed version of it

> Address.delegateCall(abi.encodePacked(abi.encodeWithSignature("abc(address,string)",
> _address, _string), _myaddress)

achieves it